# Bootstrap 3 / JS: navbar collapse and autoscroll conflict

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added a "collapse" in the Contact link of a navbar in order to hide the menu:

```
<li><div class="inactive"><a href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-right2">Contact</a></div></li>
```

It worked fine but it stopped working when the autoscroll was added. So, the auto scroll works but the collapse don't. This is the autoscroll:

```
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not(.carousel-control)').click(function () { 
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
       $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#' });
      });
    });
```

The hamburguer button has this code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-right2">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

So, I need the autoscroll and the collapse to work at the same time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Still unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did add a line to the autoscroll:

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not(.carousel-control)').click(function () { 

        $('.navbar-right2').collapse('toggle'); // <-- SOLUTION
        ...
```

Thanks